GitHub Runners issue with Visual Studio 2022? Segmentation fault with the simplest async program
I stumbled upon something that seems like a serious issue in GitHub's runner CI.
This code:
#include <future>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async, []() { return 1; });
    int r = handle.get();
    printf("Result: %d\n", r);
}

Compiled with this CMake file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project("study_ci_thread_fault")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(main main.cpp)

when compiled and built in release mode for Visual Studio 2022, will crash when run in a GitHub runner (windows 2022), with a segmentation fault!
See for example: https://github.com/pthom/study_ci_thread_fault/actions/runs/9481503691/job/26124415183
There is a full repro repository here:
https://github.com/pthom/study_ci_thread_fault
Am I the only one experiencing this? Did someone find a workaround?

Sincere question to the user who voted to close this question because "This question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline.". Please provide more details.

The C++ code is obviously correct, your CMakeLists.txt and build commands (you should include them in the question, not everyone has access to github) are also trivial and seem fine, so I would say you might report this issue as a bug to github.

Could this be related? Perhaps redistributables are not up-to-date?

I reported this to GitHub here: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/3331

@heapunderrun: Thanks a lot! This band aid somehow "fixes" the issue: https://github.com/pthom/study_ci_thread_fault/actions/runs/9482054403/job/26126124454 (by adding an incantation "#define _DISABLE_CONSTEXPR_MUTEX_CONSTRUCTOR")

@heapunderrun: If you are interested in reputation points, please provide your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as a correct answer

...And it seems that the issue was fixed in the previous ... minutes... The action now runs correctly without the #define incantation. I don't know if someone's stumbled upon my SO post here, or if it is because the issue was already extremely active on GitHub.
